# Notification API not supported by Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, notifications

I have to implement the native javascript Notifications API in my app.
I have tested this very simple code:

```
new Notification("Hello world")
```

In Firefox (mobile and desktop) it works as it should, but on Chrome (v69) it doesn't.
It doesn't even show any error.

If I do

```
console.log(Notification.permission)
```

It returns

> true

Because it's allowed on the browser.

Does chrome not support Notification API or is there something else that I check for?